# How I can show a json array in datagrid

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to show a json with one field (called schema.fields) in type of array. Can i show it as list/grid instead of text? It is something like below. However, it does not work.

```
export const SchemaEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit title={<SchemaTitle />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <DisabledInput source="id" label="Topic Name" />
            <TextInput source="schema.name" label="Desc." />
            <DisabledInput source="schema.type" label="Schema Type" />
            <NumberInput source="version" label="Schema Version" />
            <RawJsonRecordSpecificField source="schema.fields" label="fields" />
            <Datagrid bodyOptions={{ stripedRows: true, showRowHover: true}} >
                <TextField source="schema.fields.name" label="field name" />
                <TextField source="schema.fields.type" label="field type" />
            </Datagrid>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

My json format is

```
{
    "subject": "output_value",
    "version": 2,
    "id": 4,
    "schema": {
                "type":"record",
                "name":"test",
                "fields":[
                           {"name":"name","type":"string"},
                           {"name":"cnt", "type":"long"}
                         ]
               }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will not work. You aren't really providing Datagrid with the props that it needs to show your data. Wrap your datagrid in an external component like so.

```
const InlineDataGrid = (props) => {
  console.log(props) //use this to see what props are being passed to 
                     //Datagrid. All AOR components need a 'record' being passed to them that  //they display in Datagrid, record is an array.
  const record = props.record.fields
  const newProps = {...props, {record: record}} //reassign the record field in the props
  <Datagrid {...newProps} > //pass these to the component
    .....
  </Datagrid>
}
```